# Non blocking variable updates

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile

I'm going to implement non-blocking write to a variable via `Volatile.Write`. Should i use `Volatile.Read` for all consumers of this variable, or it is not necessary? What kind of impacts may occure if i read this variable as usual (without any kind of barriers)? And the same question about `Interlocked.Exchange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation of the `Volatile` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile):

> Calling one of these methods affects only a single memory access. To provide effective synchronization for a field, all access to the field must use `Volatile.Read` and `Volatile.Write`.

One of the things that may go wrong is that the compiler may emit code that reads the value of the variable into a register just once, and then keeps accessing this cached copy forever after, without ever checking to see whether the original value has changed.

Same thing with `Interlocked.Exchange`.

Generally, the best way to handle these kinds of situations is to fully encapsulate your variable inside a class exposing a property which accesses the variable via `Volatile` or `Interlocked`, thus guaranteeing that the variable will never be accessed by any other means.